# Can Blender "un-smooth" a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

When a mesh is smoothed, every selected vertex is moved towards the average position of its neighbors. Is there a way to do the opposite, given a mesh with bumps, curves and corners, to move selected vertices by small amounts opposite of what mesh smoothing would do?

Comment: related: if you receive a blender model which has smooth shade enabled, how can you undo this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. Use the smooth modifier with a negative factor.

[image: Smooth modifier]

Comment: Is the smoothing process perfectly reversible(not considering floating-point error), or will unsmoothing a mesh by the same factor as it was smoothed produce a different mesh?

Comment: It appears like it is. I'm not sure, but I tested it with Suzanne, and it appeared to get back to its original geometry.

Comment: This is not the case. Compare [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jTxa0.png) and [after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DsmLJ.png). Opening them in different browser tabs and switching quickly shows the effect.

Comment: Nice find. Good to know.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative method to reverse an operation is to add 2 shape keys, enter editmode with with a non-basis shape, edit the mesh (smooth it for example), exit editmode, then slide the shape key to a negative value you can then optionally apply it to the base mesh.

Answer (score 9):

Unsmoothing with a negative modifier is sufficient for a roughening effect, but not to fully undo a smoothing operation. To test this, I rendered Suzanne and smoothed the mesh(factor 1.0), applied the modifier, and then unsmoothed with factor -1.0.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: come on! rerender this with suzanne fitting the window and lit up with more ambient lighting, so much grey..so little suzanne..

Comment: @zeffii I was short on time so I basically threw this in a scene with the defaults. When I have some time tomorrow I'll make a better image(animated as a GIF) that shows this.

Comment: Would be great if you could find the time, @ ping me in case. I'd like to upvote.

Comment: @Leander added to todo list; hopefully will have time this week at some point.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to try is the Laplacian Smooth modifier with a negative factor.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to make a model more low-poly, then try using the [***Decimate modifier***](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html#decimate-modifier).

Comment: Or maybe the remesh.

Comment: Please try to answer the question asked. Your answering how to un-subsurf a mesh. The question is asking how to use the smooth tool in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to reverse the **Subdivision Surface** modifier, try the **Decimate Modifier** on **Un-Subdivide** mode. I find that you should usually double the subsurf level in the decimate modifier.

One of these Suzannes has been subdivided twice and then un-subdivided four times with the Decimate modifier. How well do you know your Suzannes? Which is which?

[image: Two Suzanne meshes – which is the original?]

Also take a look at a smooth-shaded version:

[image: Smooth version of above image]

<sub>Original face count: 500; processed face count: 699.</sub>

Comment: Left is the original, is it not?

Comment: Yeah, the top of the nose and the top of the mouth are the only real giveaways i see.